# how to move slider as video is being moved

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, html5-video, jwplayer

I am doing a customized  control bar. right now i am working on seek bar .i am able to play video on that particular time as the seek bar is moved . Now i need to do the vice versa that is . when my video is being played seekbar should automatically move 
i got tired of searching through google .
i know there are great number of intelligent people are in stack overflow . 
help me ,give me some idea sothat i can start again

i am kind of stuck here

thanks for your help :)
 my code is here in this link [how to make custom seek bar for player in jwplayer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16357930/how-to-make-custom-seek-bar-for-player-in-jwplayer)

and i am including here as well

```
$(document).ready(function() {



 var videoLength;

function setPosition(myPosition ) {


jwplayer().seek(myPosition);
}


// finding durartion of the video 



 jwplayer().onTime(function(event){

                                          jwplayer().play();
                                          jwplayer().pause();
                                          videoLength=event.duration;

                                          seek(videoLength);

                                          });



         function seek(pos)
{

  var position = Math.round(pos);
   $("#volume").slider({
    min: 0,
    max:position,
    value: 0,
        range: "min",
        animate: true,
      slide: function(event, ui) {
      var range = $( ".selector" ).slider( "option", "range" );
      setPosition(ui.value);
    }
  });

}                                        
 });
jwplayer code

<script type="text/javascript">

    var trackpathEn = "myCaptionsEn.vtt";
    var trackpathEn = "myCaptionsEn.vtt";
    var trackpathJa = "myCaptionsJa.vtt";
    jwplayer('player').setup({
    flashplayer: './jwplayer.flash.swf',
    file: 'example1.mp4',
    skin: "./skins/six/six.xml",
    controls: false,

    tracks: [
     { file: trackpathEn, back: false,color: 'cc0000', fontsize: 20 , label: "English", kind: "subtitles",default:true },
     { file: trackpathJa, back: false,color: 'cc0000', fontsize: 20 , label: "Japanese", kind: "subtitles" },


    ] 
  });
```

Comment: I replied to the other thread. Can you provide a link though to where this is being run? Thank you..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

hey i found the way

thanks guys all for your help

```
$("#seekBar").slider('option', 'value',slider_range);
```

just make sure that your passing right value in "slider_range"..after calculation 
and it must be integer:)